# when print report (crystal report) after setup on another machine this exception appear

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, desktop-application

> Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The System cannot find the file specified

Comment: You have missing dlls on the target machine...

Comment: The system can't find a file, can you find it on the machine? if not, thats the problem. Questions seeking debugging help must include valid code to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the crystal reports libraries that you reference in your project have the same version number (13.0.2000.0) as the crystal reports package that you install on setup at another machines.

Answer (score 0):

Its quite possible you have incorrect version of Crystal Runtime installed or may be not installed at all. These links address almost similar issues: Have a look:

[Could not load file](http://scn.sap.com/thread/3532233)

[Could not load assembly](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/forums/show/15753/could-not-load-file-or-assembly)

[Install crystal runtime](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/681843/Could-not-load-file-or-assembly-CrystalDecisions-W)